# How to go back and get new random int, when int is already in my array?

Tags: ios, arrays, nsmutablearray

I generate random ints, put them in NSNumber and save them in my Array. Now how I can say "When the Number already is in my array, go back and get a new Number?"

```
iD = arc4random() %50;
idnumber = [NSNumber numberWithInt:iD];

if ([idarray containsObject:idnumber])
{
    NSLog(@"id is in array");
    //go back

}else{
    NSLog(@"id is not in array");
    [idarray addObject:idnumber];
    //do something
}
```

Thanks for answers and sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a good use of the `do/while` loop:

```
if (idarray.count < 50) {
    NSInteger value;
    do {
        value = arc4random_uniform(50);
    } while ([idarray containsObject:@(value)]);

    [idarray addObject:@(value)];
}
```

Also note the use of `arc4random_uniform` and the use of modern boxing syntax.

Comment: Thank you! It works :-) Another question. What I can do, when all numbers are in my Array? At the moment my iPhone Simulator is doing nothing. Its hanging, when it can't find new random, thats not in my array.

Comment: What do you want to happen if the array contains all 50 numbers?

Comment: I have also arrays with less numbers :-) Can I call a method, when my do/while can't find a new number?

Comment: If your array is "full", don't call the code to add a new value since there are no new values to put in the array.